# Is adf.test is one of the ways to know whether the time series is stationary or not?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stationarity

I have time series data. Not sure whether the series is stationary or not. I applied `adf.test` and got a p-value much higher than 0.05 which I think means that the data is not stationary. I took differencing once to check the p-value again. And I see that p-value has gone below 0.05. Can I assume that the data is stationary and ready for forecast? Is there any other way to confirm this in 'R'?

Comment: Did you  made a plot before to jump into computations ?

Comment: Yes.. plotted ACF and PACF as well, I could see autocorrelation in the data. Once I took differencing, I don't see autocorrelation and adf.test also shows p-value less than 0.05

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes, ADF test tells you that after differentiation your data became stationary. No, your data is not ready for forecasting yet.

Run your time-series model using stationary data first and then check for issues such as heteroskedasticity or autocorrelation before forecasting.

You can also examine residuals graph and ACF/PACF.

**Forecasts are not accurate if heteroskedasticity/autocorrelation is present in the errors.**

Comment: The ADF test requires that there are no pulses, level shifts, seasonal pulses and local time trends in the series that need to be treated.

Comment: @Justina: Thanks for your help! I don't see autocorrelation in residuals. I will divide the data into train and test as suggested by you to be sure of forecasts.